# build a VS2015 C++ class library DLL with 3rd party .lib file

Tags: dll, lib

I'm building a VS2015 C++ class library project, in the project I need to access a 3rd party library(which is static library .lib). However, I constantly encounter the LINK2019 error (unresolved external symbol xxx referenced in funtion "..."). I am pretty sure the include directory and library directory is added to the correct setting for the .h and .lib file. And if I change the target to static library, it compiles without error. Does anyone has experience on that and shed some light on me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with the VS2015. After I restart VS2015 and re-set those include and library directory and .h/.lib file it works.